# How to remove HTML wrapper from YouTube video embeds in Gutenberg on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

in short: I had some custom post types created with the Classic Editor plugin and now I have to convert them to Gutenberg, but it keeps screwing up my URLs.

The CPTs are basically slides inside a slider, and each one of them contained a YouTube URL as the post content (or `the_content`), which was printed as the href attribute of the play icon element with `echo get_the_content` and it worked fine - the output of `echo get_the_content` was this:

`https://youtu.be/BFxGJM_sFUg`.

However, upon converting the CPT to Gutenberg blocks, the output of `get_the_content` is:

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-embed-aspect-16-9 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://youtu.be/BFxGJM_sFUg
</div></figure>
<!-- /wp:core-embed/youtube -->
```

which completely messes up the layout because of the extra HTML, so my question is - is there any way to prevent Gutenberg from adding it? I've spent hours Googleing it, found some solution that were kinda on the right track (although the issue they cover wasn't the same), but none of them worked for me. :/

Thanks!

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) - it's encouraged to do so as well. Don't edit the question - the question is still meant to be just that - a question.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a CPT, the block markup should always be wrapped the same after conversion. Use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to capture the URL string you are looking for, eg:

```
<?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            $block_content = get_the_content();
            // Find the youtube url inside <div>...</div>
            preg_match('/<div[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/s', $block_content, $match);
    
            echo $match[1]; // contains "https://youtu.be/BFxGJM_sFUg" 

        endwhile; // End the loop.
?>
```

Comment: I think this is a pretty good answer, but I actually didn't want them to be wrapped the same as before, just needed to extract the URL as I was using Magnific Popup to display the YT videos as lightbox embeds and used my own HTML markup. Maybe should've mentioned that at the beginning, sorry. :/

Comment: No worries at all, good to see you found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out on my own in the meantime. I needed to extract only the YouTube URL from the Gutenberg block as I was displaying videos as lightbox embeds with Magnific Popup. So, the code that solved my problems was this:

```
function extract_block_url( $content ) {
  $blocks = parse_blocks( $content );
  $blocks = reset( $blocks[0]['attrs'] );
  return $blocks;
}
```

The post content is parsed into an array with `parse_blocks()` and the ['url'] is selected via `reset( $blocks[0]['attrs']` as it's the first item in the ['attrs'] array

Then I pass `get_the_content()` as the function argument and echo out the function like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo extract_block_url( get_the_content() ); ?>" class="play-icon">
```